# facebook api, get access toling without login having user id

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, facebook-access-token

I'm trying to understand what is the best way to work with facebook user login. In my app in profile section it's possible for user to sync with facebook, and store it (I'm storing facebook user id in application database), and use GraphApi with provided access token in app afterwards. At this point all is fine.

But when user back to app some time later, to run some GraphApi call he need new access token, and I do not see a way how to get that access token without running user through the same facebook authentication logic with that facebook confirmation dialog.

So the question is it possible to get access token having pre-stored user id without running user again through authentication??? It's a bit weird from user perspective to see all the time that facebook dialog after he already login with facebook and save that once. Also, if facebook require always to confirm login, it seems like from app perspective it does not make sense to store id at all (any way it's possible to get it with each login)???

Also, what if I do not want for users of my app to easily change linked facebook account, but with that facebook pop up, user each time can login through different account. Is that means I need on app side afterwards compare returned id with a stored id and alert user, that he can't change already synchronized facebook account to some other?

Comment: Sending the user through the login flow again, _is_ the way to get a fresh token. _"It's a bit weird from user perspective to see all the time that facebook dialog after he already login with facebook"_ - they won't be _asked_ for anything again, if they already accepted all the asked for permissions in the past. The dialog will just pop up, and immediately close itself again; on a fast enough machine with good internet connection, most will hardly notice.

Comment: nope it's not, at least for me on flatter app, it's all the time asking if user want to auth or not, so he should click yes/no button. I think it's because in auth there is no option to provide id, like "Hey I already have user id, don't ask me nothing please and just give me access token"

Comment: _"it's all the time asking if user want to auth or not, so he should click yes/no button."_ - I am guessing you are not talking about the actual FB login dialog then, but some functionality of flutter itself? If that was not able to _recognize_ an already logged-in user, when they return, then it seems logical, that it would give a "do you want to logjn yes/no?" dialog first.

Comment: well, from what I know under the hood that flutter library using facebook js sdk, to be specific this method https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/#loginbutton

Comment: and yeah, it's logical, my main question is if there is a way to pass id, so facebook can recognize it on a fly. I'm ready to write own implementation if needed, but I can't find it on facebook documentation

Comment: `FB.getLoginStatus` is the method to check if there already is a logged-in Facebook user, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/#checklogin

Comment: but it's aslo not taking id into account, and has own expiration, after which user will be asked to login again...so again this yes/no process...

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about there, regarding the id. Fact is, the SDK itself is able to recognize a returning user - if you set `status` to true when initializing it. If a user logged into your app at some point before, and now visits your site again - then as long as they are logged into Facebook in the same browser, it will recognize that. And automatically provide you with a fresh access token.

Comment: it should but for some reason it's asking again asking me for approval to sync with the app. Okay I'll check that checkLogin functionality to be sure